# Object loading in three.js

Tags: file, 3d, three.js, load, webgl

I want to load object files in three.js. What's the best way to do this? I also want to be able to manipulate loaded objects. The objects I want to load have also texture images.
There are many ways of doing this, but I can't find which way is the best.

Comment: How are you planning on creating your models?

Comment: I create my models with blender.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the blender to three.js converter https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender to import your models to three.js and then manipulate them any way you want.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed the three.js exporter for blender. The files for 3d objects are now js files. But where can i find a good tutorial about reading the files with threejs? Or does the threejs library support this?

Comment: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_json_blender should provide the basic pointers. With google you can find the rest :-)